# How to sum different tibbles in a list?

Tags: r, list, tibble

Let's say that I have the following list

```
My_list<-list(a=structure(list(MTU..UTC. = c("01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00", "01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00", "01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 05:00 - 01.01.2016 06:00", "01.01.2016 06:00 - 01.01.2016 07:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 07:00 - 01.01.2016 08:00", "01.01.2016 08:00 - 01.01.2016 09:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 09:00 - 01.01.2016 10:00"), Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh. = c(22.39, 
                                                                                                                   20.59, 16.81, 17.41, 17.02, 15.86, 18.16, 17.73, 19.77, 23.75
                                             )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                             )),
              b=structure(list(MTU..UTC. = c("01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00", "01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00", "01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 05:00 - 01.01.2016 06:00", "01.01.2016 06:00 - 01.01.2016 07:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 07:00 - 01.01.2016 08:00", "01.01.2016 08:00 - 01.01.2016 09:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 09:00 - 01.01.2016 10:00"), Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh. = c(22.39, 
                                                                                                                   20.59, 16.81, 17.41, 17.02, 15.86, 18.16, 17.73, 19.77, 23.75
                                             )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                             )),
              c=structure(list(MTU..UTC. = c("01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00", "01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00", "01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 05:00 - 01.01.2016 06:00", "01.01.2016 06:00 - 01.01.2016 07:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 07:00 - 01.01.2016 08:00", "01.01.2016 08:00 - 01.01.2016 09:00", 
                                             "01.01.2016 09:00 - 01.01.2016 10:00"), Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh. = c(22.39, 
                                                                                                                   20.59, 16.81, 17.41, 17.02, 15.86, 18.16, 17.73, 19.77, 23.75
                                             )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                             )),
              d=structure(list(MTU..UTC. = c("01.01.2015 00:00 - 01.01.2015 01:00", 
                                             "01.01.2015 01:00 - 01.01.2015 02:00", "01.01.2015 02:00 - 01.01.2015 03:00", 
                                             "01.01.2015 03:00 - 01.01.2015 04:00", "01.01.2015 04:00 - 01.01.2015 05:00", 
                                             "01.01.2015 05:00 - 01.01.2015 06:00", "01.01.2015 06:00 - 01.01.2015 07:00", 
                                             "01.01.2015 07:00 - 01.01.2015 08:00", "01.01.2015 08:00 - 01.01.2015 09:00", 
                                             "01.01.2015 09:00 - 01.01.2015 10:00"), Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh. = c(5, 
                                                                                                                   NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I want to sum the tibble a with d (contains a lot of NAs) so that I can get the following result

```
$a
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  MTU..UTC.                           Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh.
  <chr>                                                   <dbl>
1 01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00                      27.4 #New value
2 01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00                      20.6
3 01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00                      16.8
4 01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00                      17.4
5 01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00                      17.0

$b
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  MTU..UTC.                           Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh.
  <chr>                                                   <dbl>
1 01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00                      22.4
2 01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00                      20.6
3 01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00                      16.8
4 01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00                      17.4
5 01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00                      17.0

$c
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  MTU..UTC.                           Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh.
  <chr>                                                   <dbl>
1 01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00                      22.4
2 01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00                      20.6
3 01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00                      16.8
4 01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00                      17.4
5 01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00                      17.0
```

I tried to get the result using `reduce` , but the function sum all the elements in the list and i want to sum only this 2 tibbles and keep the others.

Comment: is it intentional that d is 2015, while all others are 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tedious, but here you go:

I would recommend starting off with converting the list to a tibble using the `enframe` command - then you can use `unnest` to get a nice data structure to work with.

Because the dates don't match (d is 2015, all others 2016), we need to either 1) add one year to the date column (potentially using the `lubridate` package) or 2) we simply add the columns to the new data. This is not ideal **as it only works with data.frames that have the same row number**, but is what is illustrated below.

We start by filtering out the values of d in a separate data.frame.

Then we add it back to the original one, which we have modified with `pivot_wider` so that each of a, b, and c are now separate columns.

Then we use a `mutate` command to sum a and d (Note: here we assume that d is 0 if it's missing to get to the values you use above).

```r
library(tidyverse)
My_list %>% 
  enframe %>% # convert list to tibble
  unnest(value) %>% # convert list column to rows
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # clean the names (optional - janitor package)
  filter(name == "d") %>% # get only the values where the group is d
  rename(d = day_ahead_price_eur_m_wh) %>% 
  select(d)-> d

My_list %>% 
  enframe %>% # convert list to tibble
  unnest(value) %>% # convert list column to rows
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # clean the names (optional - janitor package)
  filter(name != "d") %>% # get all groups apart from d
  pivot_wider(id_cols = mtu_utc, names_from = name, values_from = day_ahead_price_eur_m_wh) %>% # pivot the data so that each group is a column
  bind_cols(.,d) %>% # add the d column to the data
  mutate(d = ifelse(is.na(d),0,d), # convert all missing values in d to a 0
         a = a + d) %>% # sum a and d
  select(-d) %>% # remove d (optional)
  pivot_longer(-mtu_utc) %>% # get back to a longer dataframe (optional)
  arrange(name) -> result # arrange sorts the data not by date but by group
```

Now `result` looks like this:

```r
> result
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   mtu_utc                             name  value
   <chr>                               <chr> <dbl>
 1 01.01.2016 00:00 - 01.01.2016 01:00 a      27.4
 2 01.01.2016 01:00 - 01.01.2016 02:00 a      20.6
 3 01.01.2016 02:00 - 01.01.2016 03:00 a      16.8
 4 01.01.2016 03:00 - 01.01.2016 04:00 a      17.4
 5 01.01.2016 04:00 - 01.01.2016 05:00 a      17.0
 6 01.01.2016 05:00 - 01.01.2016 06:00 a      15.9
 7 01.01.2016 06:00 - 01.01.2016 07:00 a      18.2
 8 01.01.2016 07:00 - 01.01.2016 08:00 a      17.7
 9 01.01.2016 08:00 - 01.01.2016 09:00 a      19.8
10 01.01.2016 09:00 - 01.01.2016 10:00 a      23.8
# ... with 20 more rows
```

If you want to have it back as a list, then you need to do the following:

```
result %>%   
  group_split(name)
```

Comment: The code functions very well. Only one observation, the names of the variables are `MTU..UTC.` and `Day.ahead.Price..EUR.MWh.` I changed the name for running your code with my original data.

Comment: Glad this works! And indeed I slightly changed your column names with the `clean_names()` command as I personally advise against using a `.` in a column name :)

Answer (score 1):

Base R Solution:

```
# Clean vector names; store list elements back in a new list:
# cleaned_name_list => list of tibbles: 
cleaned_name_list <- lapply(My_list, function(x){
    setNames(
      x, 
      tolower(gsub("\\W+", "_", trimws(names(x), whitespace = "\\s+|[[:punct:]]")))
    )
  }
)

# String scalar denoting the name of the tibble to add to the other tibbles:
# to_add => character vector
to_add <- "d"

# Integer vector denoting which list elements are to have to_add element added
# on: to_keep_idx => integer vector
to_keep_idx <- which(names(cleaned_name_list) != to_add)

# Add the element to all other elements in the list: 
# cleaned_name_list => list of tibbles:
cleaned_name_list[to_keep_idx] <- lapply(
  cleaned_name_list[to_keep_idx], 
  function(x){
    y <- cleaned_name_list[[to_add]]
    data.frame(
      mtu_utc = x$mtuutc,
      dayahead_price_eur_mwh = 
      rowSums(
        cbind(
          adjustment = y$dayahead_price_eur_mwh[match(x$mtuutc, y$mtuutc)],
          act_price = x$dayahead_price_eur_mwh
        ),
        na.rm = TRUE
      )
    )
  }
)
```